# Moving file security from one server to another (asp.net sites, IIS)

Tags: asp.net, windows, security, iis, file

I am running windows server with asp.net websites and sql server 2008 and IIS 6. It is working fine.

Now I need to move my asp.net websites to another windows server and I have hard time setting correct file security for the new server.

Is there any way to compare or move or see difference file security between two servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice question, I have never think to do something like that :)

Use AccessEnum tool from sysinternals

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897332.aspx

to see and compare your security access on your files and directories.